# or-tools how to use OnlyEnforceIf in this case

Tags: python-3.x, or-tools

Example:

```
boolVar = 
[[2,0,0,2],
 [0,0,0,0],
 [0,1,0,0],
 [0,0,1,0]]
```

For every sub-array, the sum could be greater than 3 or 0

I have tried using `OnlyEnforceIf`, but OnlyEnforceIf takes an boolvar as a parameter, how can I do this?

```
for i in range(n):
  model.Add(sum(result[i]) > 3).OnlyEnforceIf(sum(result[i]) > validMinSum)
  model.Add(sum(result[i]) == 0).OnlyEnforceIf(sum(result[i]) == 0)
```

The error i got is `AttributeError: 'BoundedLinearExpression' object has no attribute 'Index'`

Comment: Create an aux boolvar, see https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/ortools/sat/doc/channeling.md#python-code

Comment: @Stradivari I have read that, but the problem is how do I link the boolVar to the condition I'm currently using?

Comment: How about simply adding `sum(result[i]) != 2`  and `sum(result[i]) != 1`?

Comment: Laurent Perron always attaches a link to https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/ortools/sat/doc/channeling.md when someone asks about creating a boolean equivalent to a given numeric comparison expression.

Comment: As stated in your post, `sum(result[i]) == 1` and `sum(result[i]) == 2` would be valid solutions because the OnlyEnforceIf part would each be false (assuming it were a BoolVar...) and the constraints wouldn't be enforced.

Comment: `b = model.NewBoolVar('')` `model.Add(sum(result[i]) > 3). OnlyEnforceIf(b)` `model.Add(...).OnlyEnforceif(b.Not())`

Comment: @ChristopherHamkins, what i intend is to let `sum(result[i]) ==1` and `sum(result[i]) == 2` to be invalid, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @Stradivari, but that way, what is the b for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elaborating on @Stradivari 's comment and the link he posted: You need to construct a boolean variable that is enforced to be equivalent to the expression you want. For example:

```
// Implement b == (x >= 5).
model.Add(x >= 5).OnlyEnforceIf(b);
model.Add(x < 5).OnlyEnforceIf(b.Not());
```

Or in terms of your question:

```
# ... assuming result is already defined as IntVar[][] jagged array
sum_greater_than_min = model.NewBoolVar("Sum > validMinSum");
model.Add(LinearExpression.Sum(result[i]) > 3).OnlyEnforceIf(sum_greater_than_min);
model.Add(LinearExpression.Sum(result[i]) <= 3).OnlyEnforceIf(sum_greater_than_min.Not);
sum_equal_zero = model.NewBoolVar("Sum==0");
model.Add(LinearExpression.Sum(result[i]) == 0).OnlyEnforceIf(sum_equal_zero);
model.Add(LinearExpression.Sum(result[i]) != 0).OnlyEnforceIf(sum_equal_zero.Not);
# Now enforce that one of the booleans must be true
a = model.NewBoolVar("");
model.AddMinEquality(a, [sum_greater_than_min, sum_equal_zero])); 
model.Add(a == 1);
```

Edit based on @Stradivari's comment to simplify using only one BoolVar (and corrected a typo above):

```
# ... assuming result is already defined as IntVar[][] jagged array
sum_greater_than_min = model.NewBoolVar("Sum > validMinSum");
model.Add(LinearExpression.Sum(result[i]) > 3).OnlyEnforceIf(sum_greater_than_min);
model.Add(LinearExpression.Sum(result[i]) == 0).OnlyEnforceIf(sum_greater_than_min.Not);
```

If sum_greater_than_min is false, then the constraint sum == 0 is enforced. If it is true, then sum > 3 is enforced.

Comment: As he only has 2 options, one boolean is enough because you can use the Not for the second constraint